# Similar to TextExpander App but simulating typewriting text effect

Tags: text

I'm looking for an app similar to [TextExpander](http://smilesoftware.com/TextExpander/features.html) but I need that the **expanded snippet** to be shown simulating typewriting text effect.

Something like shown [in this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YU5yCHhiuk).

If not posible, can I do it with Automator?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean write something in monospace font, I use TextExpander for inserting the clipboard in a specific font, where I choose a monospace font (I chose Monaco since it seems like it's available on many platforms/OS). Handy for when citing a block of code in an email for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by typewriting text effect. If you want to delays before the keystrokes, you might use scripts like this:

```
delay 0.5 -- time to release modifier keys if for example the script is run with command-R
tell application "System Events"
    repeat with c in items of "example"
        keystroke c
        delay (random number from 0.03 to 0.2)
    end repeat
end tell
```

If you want to insert the text in a monospace font, TextExpander supports changing the font if you use rich text snippets.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are looking at alternatives to TextExpander too:

This is something I spent a while looking at as after TextExpander went to a subscription model I decided to look elsewhere as I really only needed the basic core features, I settled on [Dash](https://kapeli.com/dash) but there are a number of alternatives, I tried [aText](http://www.trankynam.com/atext/) but the application appeared to be unsupported at the time.

I like the [site AlternativeTo.net to find alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/textexpander/) to common products.